# What are "names which are not lvalues"?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, value-categories

There's an entry in the [errata](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html) of *Effective Modern C++* which says that

> not all names are lvalues

What are these names? Specifically,

1. is Scott just referring to the `nullptr` and `this` named prvalues?
2. Are there any others?
3. In case the answer to 1 is *yes*, then what makes `nullptr` special with respect to `true` and `false`? They are all values of some type (`true`/`false` of type `bool`, `nullptr` of type `std::nullptr_t`). After all `true` stays to `bool` just like `1` stays to `int`, and `1` is not a "name which is not an lvalue", is it? At this point I'd ask *why is `true` not a name then?*

Comment: E.g. an enumerator - `X` declared as `enum E { X };`

Comment: Back in the olden days, "lvalue" meant a name that could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment (and, similarly, an "rvalue" could only appear on the right-hand side). So, basically, any name that you can't assign a value to is not an lvalue. (note the word **assign**, which is not the same as **initialize**; `const int x = 5;` initializes `x`, but `x` is not an lvalue, because you cannot write `x = 3;`).

Comment: @PeteBecker isn't that only a _non-modifiable lvalue_?

Comment: @Enrico -- as I said, that was back in the olden days. There was no notion of a non-modifiable lvalue, since an lvalue by definition could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment, i.e., it was modifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression `X` where `X` is the name of an enumerator (declared e.g. as `enum E { X };`) has *rvalue* value category.

---

Similarly for non-type template parameters (hat tip to @PasserBy), as in

```
template <int X>
int f() { return X; /* X is an rvalue */}
```

Comment: And template parameters, template themselves, labels, namespaces and packs. Not sure about bit fields.

Comment: @PasserBy Most of these can't be used as expressions (being an lvalue is a property of an expression, so "a name is an lvalue" can only be understood as "an *id-expression* that consists of this name is an lvalue"), but I grant you non-type template parameters. Answer modified accordingly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, would you comment on the points in my question? For instance, it's not obvious to me if `true`, which is an rvalue, is indeed a _name_.

Comment: `true` is not a name (it's not introduced by a declaration). It's a keyword, denoting a literal.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so also `nullptr` and `this` are not names but keywords?

Comment: Correct. `nullptr` is also a literal (of type `nullptr_t`). `this` is a kind of expression.